# Python: Plot from second and third columns while picking parameter values from the first one

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have three-column data in a file named "sample1.dat" and a code that reads the columns and tries to plot the 3rd column against the 2nd column. I pick up parameter values from the 1st column elements as long as their values remain the same.

"sample1.dat" reads

```
0   1   1
0   2   4
0   3   9
0   4   16
0   5   25
0   6   36
1   1   1
1   2   8
1   3   27
1   4   64
1   5   125
1   6   216
2   1   1
2   2   16
2   3   81
2   4   256
2   5   625
2   6   1296
```

And my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('sample1.dat')
x = data[:,0] 
y = data[:,1] 
z = data[:,2]
L = len(data)

col = ['r','g','b']
x0 = x[0]; j=0; jold=-1


for i in range(L):
  print('j, col[j]=',j, col[j])
  if x[i] == x0:
     print('y[i], z[i]=',y[i],z[i])
     if i==0 or j != jold: # j-index decides new or the same paramet
         label = 'parameter = {}'.format(x0)
     else:
         label = ''
     print('label =',label)
     plt.plot(y[i], z[i], color=col[j], marker='o', label=label)
  else:
     x0 = x[i] # Update when x-value changes, 
            # i.e. pick up the next parameter value
     i -= 1 # Shift back else we miss the 1st point for new x-value 
     j += 1; jold = j

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('2nd column') 
plt.ylabel('3rd column')
plt.savefig('sample1.png') 
plt.show()
```

The plot outcome:

[image]

One can clearly see that two issues persist:

1. The legends appear only for the first parameter though I tried to avoid the repitition in my code.
2. The default linestyle is not appearing though the legends show line plus marker plots.

How could I resolve these or is there a smarter way of coding to fulfill the same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is due to some strange logic involving `j`,`jold` and `x0`.  The code can be simplified by drawing all `y,z` for each x-value at once. Numpy allows selecting the `y`'s corresponding to a given `x0` as `y[x==x0s]`.

The second issue can be solved by explicitly setting the desired linestyle, i.e. `ls=''`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('sample1.dat')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
z = data[:, 2]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

for x0, color in zip(np.unique(x), colors):
    plt.plot(y[x == x0], z[x == x0], color=color, marker='o', ls='', label=f'parameter = {x0:.0f}')

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('2nd column')
plt.ylabel('3rd column')
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with colors per x value]

An alternative approach would use the seaborn library, which does the selecting and coloring without a lot of intervention, for example:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(x=y, y=z, hue=x, palette=['r', 'g', 'b'])
```

Seaborn can automatically add labels if the data is organized as a dictionary or a pandas dataframe:

```
data = {'first column': x.astype(int),
        'second column': y,
        'third column': z}
sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='second column', y='third column', hue='first column', palette=['r', 'g', 'b'])
```

[image: sns.scatterplot]

Comment: Feel free to reference my answer while editing yours. Thanks @JohanC

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your answer while I was editing mine. Yours is certainly a good approach, nice work. Seaborn is an excellent fit for this type of plots.

Comment: No worries. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks and sorry for the belated response. Your versions work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want in a few lines by using pandas and seaborn.
If you add column names (for instance `A`, `B`, and `C`) to the data in the `sample1.dat` file as follow:

```py
A   B   C
0   1   1
0   2   4
0   3   9
0   4   16
0   5   25
0   6   36
1   1   1
1   2   8
1   3   27
1   4   64
1   5   125
1   6   216
2   1   1
2   2   16
2   3   81
2   4   256
2   5   625
2   6   1296
```

You can then load your data in a pandas dataframe and plot it with seaborn:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_fwf('sample1.dat')
col = ['r','g','b']
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='B',y='C',hue='A',palette=col)
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: Probably you could read the original file (without adding the column names into the file) via `df = pd.read_fwf(..., header=None, names=['A','B','C'])`

Comment: Good point, that's definitely a nicer way to load the data without having to amend the file

Comment: Thanks. Sorry @jylls, what does `read_fwf` do here? Secondly, I don't get any points plotted from your code. @JohanC's suggestion shows some points plotted but they're wrong and the y-axis ticking shows some garbage fonts!

Comment: `read_fwf` is a pandas function that reads your data file and turns it into a dataframe. Make sure, that your data is in the same format as the format in my answer and that the file as the same name. To show the plot, you might have to call `plt.show`